# Atomic read and write in one query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, concurrency, insert-into

I have an app that requires a single instance of a task to be run. In order to check whether a current instance of the task is already running, i check the status of the task. If the task has a combination of one or more of those statuses, then it knows the task is already running and should skip the task for now. These tasks can be called from multiple places so i could have a hundred or so calls for the task to be run in a minute.

I have the following query on Oracle 11g.

The SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Log2 (LogID, Action, EventDateTime)
  SELECT 102211, 2, SYSDATE FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT LogID FROM Log2 T3 WHERE T3.Param2 = 102 AND T3.Action = 34 AND T3.AuditLogID NOT IN
       (SELECT T2.LogID FROM Log2 T1, Log2 T2 WHERE (T1.Action IN (1,2,3) AND T2.Action = 6 AND T1.Param3=T2.Param3 AND T1.Param2 = 102))
    );
```

At the moment the above query will sometimes allow 2 records to be inserted at the same time (eventDateTime tells me that).How can i ensure that this does not happen ? Do i need to add some locking hints ?  I thought the whole query was atomic. The JDBC connection is on auto commit. 
There are several parts of the app that update this table. i only want this locking to happens for the tasks item as stated above. Other parts of the app that add records to this Log2 table only ever insert one record at a time, so this single instance behaviour is not required for those other parts.

Thanks

Comment: You could maybe use dbms_lock package, or write a stored proc with a "select.. for update"

Comment: The query is atomic, but sees only commited data - it doesn't see uncommited data. Consider this case: at time T1 session1 inserts a new record (but not commits) - at time T2 another session2 runs a query, but since it doesn't see the new record inserted by Session1 yet , then inserts a record too - at time T3  session1 commits - at time T4 session2 commits - finally there are 2 new records in the table. You need some kind of additional synchronizaton - `select fo update` or `dbms_lock` as  @OldProgrammer suggested.